# blade displaying multi array data with or

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I want to display the old data in blade after redirect.
So if the old data is empty or doesn't exists it should display my passed 
task data multidimensional array.

Laravel:

```
redirect()->withInput();
```

Blade:

```
name ="task[{{$dayKey}}][]"
value="{{old('task.'.$dayKey.'.'.$key) or $task}}"
```

Separately `{{old('task.'.$dayKey.'.'.$key)` and `$task` works fine but 
if i used `or` the output is every time `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `set default` value with comma separated `second` argument.

```
value="{{old('task.'.$dayKey.'.'.$key, $task)}}"
```

This will `check` for `old` input value, if there is no old input value then will `set` the default one.